# name 'b' is not defined when imported from unit test

Tags: python, python-import

I have just created a unit test for my code and placed it in a test directory. It tests the functionality of module a which depends on module b. My directory tree looks like:

```
├── src
|   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── a.py
│   ├── b.py
├── test/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── unit.py
```

The unit test looks like:

```
import unittest
from src import a

class TestUtils(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_function(self):
    self.assertEqual(a.func(), 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run with:

```
python test/unit.py
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/unit.py", line 2, in <module>
    from src import a
  File "/home/src/a.py", line 13, in <module>
    from b import B
 ImportError: No module named 'b'
```

What can I do to keep this structure and be able to run both my program and the test?

Comment: kindly include full traceback

Comment: I've updated the original post to include the full traceback

Comment: Maybe try `from .b import B`?

Comment: Yes I have tried that it works for the test but then my normal program fails with ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Only `test/` is added to the module search path. You'll need to explicitly add the absolute path to `src` to the python module search path.

Comment: How do I do that neatly? I could probably add it to PYTHONPATH but that seems like a less than ideal solution.

Comment: with the `from .b import B`, what happens if you go up one directory and try `python -m src.a` ? (assuming `a` is where your main is) and `python -m test.unit` ?